# MemoryError occurred while running a calculation algorithm for the number pi

Tags: python

I'm a 14-year-old student who has very little experience with programming, and I came up with an idea for calculating the value of the constant pi using the equation of a circle.

```
import random
startval = 0
a = 0
b = 0
e = 'start'
avpi = []
intro = ''' CALCULATING PI
    DEVELOPER : J.Y.C.'''
print(' ' + "="*50)
print(" "*1)
print('   ' + intro)
print(" "*1)
print(' ' + "="*50)
print(' ')
print('''   COMMANDS : 
    Execute Program : 'start'
    Stop Program : press 'Ctrl+C'
    View Source : 'view'
''')
ipt = input()
if ipt =='view':
    print('''
''')

while ipt == e:
    x = random.randint(-10000,10000)
    y = random.randint(-10000,10000)
    if x**2 + y**2 <= 100000000:
        a = a+1
        b = b+1
        avpi.append(4*a/b)
    else: 
        b = b+1
        avpi.append(4*a/b)
    if b%1000000==0:
        print(''' 

        ''')
        print('total: '+str(b))
        print('in circle: '+str(a))
        print('average calculation of pi : ' + str(sum(avpi)/b) )
        print(''' 

        ''')
    if b == 10**8: continue
```

The code itself seems very simple. I want to keep this running for at least an hour to get my results as precise as possible, but it keeps shutting down with this after a mere few minutes.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Study\python\CALPI.py", line 31, in <module>
    avpi.append(4*a/b)
MemoryError
```

is there anything I can do to prevent this? Or is this just all that my laptop is able to handle?

Comment: you can stop appending to `avpi`

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses a lot of memory, because you save a new number in `avpi` in every loop iteration.

You are only accessing `avpi` when you print your result and then you do not need access to all elements of `avpi`, but only to its sum.

So instead of saving numbers in `avpi` in every iteration you could just save the sum of your values instead. To do that create a new variable `avpi_sum = 0` outside your while loop and replace `avpi.append(4*a/b)` with `avpi_sum = avpi_sum + (4*a/b)`.
Make sure that you then print `avpi_sum` instead of `sum(avpi)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great project! But there are a few things that may not be working as you expect.

1. At any point, `4*a/b` is your best estimate of pi. There's no need to keep a list of all the values of this expression, unless you later want to analyze how quickly the process converged. If you don't create this list, you won't run out of memory. If needed, as others have noted, you can store the sum of all previous values and use that to calculate the historical average. But a better measure of convergence might be how much `4*a/b` has changed in the last 1000000 iterations. You could show that by saving the current value of `4*a/b` whenever `b % 1000000 == 0`, then reporting and updating the stored value the next time the condition is true (i.e. report `prev_pi`, then set `prev_pi = 4*a/b`).
2. The `if` statement at the end of the loop has no effect, because the loop will resume at the top (continue) whether it is true or false. If you want to ask the user whether they want to continue at this point, you may need to put a prompt here and then use `break` if they want to stop.
3. Your algorithm will reach an upper limit of quality because you are only considering integer points on the plane. It will work better if you consider floating-point coordinates instead. You can do that by using `random.uniform` instead of `random.randint`.

Some smaller things that are just good code practice:

1. You can move `b = b + 1` and the `append` call (if you're keeping it) outside of the `if` statement so you don't have to repeat them. That may also clarify your algorithm a bit.
2. You can print a blank line by putting `\n` in your string, e.g., `print('\n\nTotal:{}'.format(b))`

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but maybe the problem is that avpi list will grow without any control. I would suggest you store only the value somewhere else, instead of storing the whole list

What happens if you try this? Is the problem solved?

```
import random
startval = 0
a = 0
b = 0
e = 'start'
avpi_sum = 0
intro = ''' CALCULATING PI
    DEVELOPER : J.Y.C.'''
print(' ' + "="*50)
print(" "*1)
print('   ' + intro)
print(" "*1)
print(' ' + "="*50)
print(' ')
print('''   COMMANDS :
    Execute Program : 'start'
    Stop Program : press 'Ctrl+C'
    View Source : 'view'
''')
ipt = input()
if ipt =='view':
    print('''
''')

while ipt == e:
    x = random.randint(-10000,10000)
    y = random.randint(-10000,10000)
    if x**2 + y**2 <= 100000000:
        a = a+1
        b = b+1
    else:
        b = b+1
    avpi_sum += 4*a/b
    if b%1000000==0:
        print('''

        ''')
        print('total: '+str(b))
        print('in circle: '+str(a))
        print('average calculation of pi : ' + str(avpi_sum/b) )
        print('''

        ''')
    if b == 10**8: break
```